# CSS element moving

Tags: html, css

Hello I have had this issue since the beginning of my web development start. When I zoom in the container moves in too. any way i can solve this?

```css
.darkslidecont{
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    left: 80%;
    display: block;
    flex-wrap: flex;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h1 id="welcomeText"><u>Welcome to My Portfolio!</u></h1>
    <div class="darkslidecont">
    </div>
</header>
```

I have played around with the positions and display but no luck

Comment: Also add your html file. Better to make an snippet.

Comment: Added sorry about that.

Comment: you have `left = 80%` so of course when you zoom in it moves too

Comment: ah in future what should I use like vh or px?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset css

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.darkslidecont{
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    left: 80%;
    display: block;
    flex-wrap: flex;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h1 id="welcomeText"><u>Welcome to My Portfolio!</u></h1>
    <div class="darkslidecont">
    </div>
</header>
```